# Adding shape to stage as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm not sure if I'm over or under thinking this however I've got this scenario. I wish to be able to add (for now) a triangle to the page using multiple classes. The first one being adding actionscript to a frame in flash the second an actual class. Now, can I do this? Or am I silly thinking I can? I wish to do this so I can create my background as a dynamically created area where thinks I can interact with are placed on as instances of a class.

On frame

```
import flash.display.Stage;

var sides:Sides=new Sides();
stage.addChild(sides);
this.addChild(sides);
```

On class

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Shape;

        public class Sides extends Shape {
            public function Sides() {
                var triangleHeight:uint = 100; 
            var triangle:Shape = new Shape(); 

            // red triangle, starting at point 0, 0 
            triangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); 
            triangle.graphics.moveTo(triangleHeight / 2, 0); 
            triangle.graphics.lineTo(triangleHeight, triangleHeight); 
            triangle.graphics.lineTo(0, triangleHeight); 
            triangle.graphics.lineTo(triangleHeight / 2, 0);
            triangle.graphics.endFill();
            trace("Into construct");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I have is that the actual triangle does not appear on the screen it's blank. I know the constructor is ran, however I get no actual output as such.

I hope I made myself clear. If anyone can suggest a better solution I would love to hear it. My scenario is this.
I wish to create a world that other movie-clips can interact with. I will be creating lines to represent them. Now is it better to do it dynamically generated or is there a way to have some sort of base class that all of the other ones run off where that allows me to have random width. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

you create an instance of a Shape within your Sides constructor to which you draw the triangle however this shape is never added to a display list, instead you add your instance of Sides (which itself has nothing drawn) to a display list.

Because your Sides class is extending Shape you don't need another instance of a Shape, your instance of Sides itself is a Shape and you can draw directly to it like so:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Shape;

        public class Sides extends Shape {
            public function Sides() {
                var triangleHeight:uint = 100;

                // red triangle, starting at point 0, 0 
                this.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); 
                this.graphics.moveTo(triangleHeight / 2, 0); 
                this.graphics.lineTo(triangleHeight, triangleHeight); 
                this.graphics.lineTo(0, triangleHeight); 
                this.graphics.lineTo(triangleHeight / 2, 0);
                this.graphics.endFill();
                trace("Into construct");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Should I use `stage.addChild(sides);`or 
`this.addChild(sides);` Any thoughts on a better way to implement my final goal?

Comment: Not sure I understand your original question 100%, but any class you define which extends anything with a display list (i.e. DisplayObjectContainer, DisplayObject, Shape, Sprite, MovieClip) can have your triangle added to it, something like `var blob:MySpriteExtendingClass = new MySpriteExtendingClass(); blob.addChild(new Sides());`

Comment: I'm saying for example. I wish to create multiple lines with random x lengths. In either set places or random locations. If that makes sense?

Comment: @milks That is incorrect. Only objects that extend `DisplayObjectContainer` can add a child `DisplayObject` and only select classes have access to the `Graphics` class (meaning it is not implemented by `DisplayObject` itself, but rather its children).